# Pandas update column by comparing two column to list

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like an easy question, but I'm struggling to find a solution. I have a pandas df with two columns (ticker, target) and a list called stock_symbols.  In simple terms here's what I want to do (note-this is not my code):

```
For each value in df['ticker']:
    If df['ticker'] is in [ticker_list]:
        df['target'] = 1
    Else:
        df['target'] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for creating `boolean mask` which is converted to `int` (thanks [Michael Hoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499044/pandas-update-column-by-comparing-two-column-to-list/43499086#comment74052450_43499086)):

```
df['target'] = df['ticker'].isin(ticker_list).astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
ticker_list = ['s','f']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['s','d','f']})
print (df)
  ticker
0      s
1      d
2      f

df['target'] = df['ticker'].isin(ticker_list).astype(int)
print (df)
  ticker  target
0      s       1
1      d       0
2      f       1
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I wasn't connecting the dots of assigning it back to the column value.  What tripped me up was the examples I saw created a new df.  Thanks!